# worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess) after task started

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

Setup: Celery 3.1, broker=RabbitMQ, backend=Redis.

Scenario:
Having a task is `state=STARTED (running)` my worker is being restarted. I'm getting `worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)` message (stdout). The worker successfully restarted but the task is stuck on `STARTED` state (monitored via flower) and nothing happen.

Desired state: I wish that the stuck task will run again (or fail before the shutdown) - and not be ignored and left as 'STARTED' forever.

Comment: I've the same problem but I can't understand what cause it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True` solved the problem

Comment: Could you elaborate please? How do I use that? Where should I put it?

Comment: It's part of Celey's configuration: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_acks_late